# Python socket speed asymmetrical

Tags: python, sockets, bigdata

I'm writing python code that synchronizes workers and a master using either TCP/IP sockets or UNIX domain sockets.

The data that transits on these sockets is bidirectionnal, not often sent, but huge (400MB~). The speed server->client in the handler is fast enough (20sec) but the other way is unbearable (40min!)

Do you have any clue why the socket got through "accept" of the server is faster at sending, or the other faster at receiving, I do not even know.

Here is how the client connects:

```
  self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  try:
     if use_tcp:
        self.sock.connect((host, websocket_port))
     else:
        self.sock.connect(unix_socket)
     self.wfile = self.sock.makefile('wb', 0)
     self.sock.sendall("connect")
     self.request_parameters()
  except:
     raise
```

And sends data

```
  print("Sending %d bytes of data..." % sys.getsizeof(serialized))
  try:
     self.wfile.write("once" + serialized + "end")
     self.wfile.flush()
     print("Written and sent...")
  except Exception,e:
     print("Too large to be sent? :'(")
     print(e)
```

The server is a SocketServer one:

```
class TCPUnixServer(ss.TCPServer):
   address_family = socket.AF_UNIX

   def __init__(self, addr, handler):
      try:
         os.unlink(addr)
      except OSError:
         if os.path.exists(addr):
             raise
      ss.TCPServer.__init__(self, addr, handler)

def start_parameter_server(model, num_epochs, warmup_data=None, test_data=None):
   if use_tcp:
      server = ss.TCPServer(unix_socket, ParameterServerWebsocketHandler)
   else:
      server = TCPUnixServer(unix_socket, ParameterServerWebsocketHandler)
```

To read data, both client and server do so:

```
 while True:
     rcv = self.sock.recv(4096)
     if rcv.endswith("end"):
        parameters += rcv.rstrip("end")
        break
     parameters += rcv
```

Comment: Do you have the same behavior if you exchange computers? Is there some anti-virus on the server that inspect all incoming packet?

Comment: Well both processes are on the same computer at the moment... No antivirus, firewall port open. Really can't figure out why.

Comment: How do your server send data to client? How do the server opens the file to send?

Comment: Data in bothe directions are big serialized numpy arrays, no file is ever opened. Here is a snippet for the server (sorry for no code indentation in comments):

      self.server.lock.acquire()
      parameters = self.server.model.get_parameters()
      self.server.lock.release()
      serialized = self.server.model.serialize(parameters)
      self.wfile.write("ok" + serialized + "end")
      self.wfile.flush()
      print("Sent the parameters to a friend")